# tile above fiberglass shower - can I apply directly to drywall?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, shower, tile

Question says it all...

I have a fiberglass shower form and I want to class it up a bit, so I'm going to put tile above the form and extend it up to our extra tall cieling. My questions are:

1. Is it possible or safe to mortar tile directly to drywall?
2. If not, what would I need to replace the drywall with so I can attach the tile to the wall?

Any links to good guides would be appreciated.

Comment: Be sure that the fiberglass is sealed to the wall. In the event water condenses on the tile you don't want it migrating behind the fiberglass.

Comment: coat it with redguard first if in doubt.

Comment: @PlatinumGoose thanks, I'll check it first. Once the tile is up, would I need to seal the seam along the top of the fiberglass where it meets the tile? Maybe with a ceramic tile caulk?

Comment: I'd seal it to the wall before you tile and seal it after you tile.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a party in the shower, the area above the fiberglass gets very little water.  Go ahead and tile over the drywall. It is likely a moisture resistant drywall anyway. I have tiled these areas many times, with no problems.
Use a thin set rated for the tile you are using. Grout carefully, leaving no holes or gaps.
Good Luck

Comment: Thanks RMDman, another comment above mentions coating the wall with redguard, would you agree with this?

Comment: The redguard wouldn't hurt.  It is pricy and if you are only coating above the shower, you will have to buy more than you need.  If the shower is used daily by multiple people it could be good insurance.  A second bath that gets occasional use it would be a waste.